# PHP SwiftMailer - Server with multiple IP addresses

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I've got an already configured mail server with 12 IP addresses.

Do I need any special configuration of SwiftMailer to use it properly ?

Or its only my server job to use these IP addresses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be connecting to your mail server with SwiftMailer using it's hostname rather than one of the IP addresses and you will be fine.

Comment: Im currently using host, so the rest should be handled by server itself isn't it?

Comment: Yeah.  You don't need to worry about anything else once you are using the hostname :)